# Local Notification Banner and sound not working in Foreground Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

Im trying to implement the local notification to my app and I implemented the local notification but the problem is .... I'm not getting the ***Notification BANNER and SOUND*** when my app is in the ***foreground***. But it is ***working good*** when my app is in ***background***.
How to bring the notification banner and sound in foreground.. Is that possible?

this is my piece of code...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Handle launching from a notification
    UILocalNotification *locationNotification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (locationNotification) {
        // Set icon badge number to zero
            application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{

    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {
        NSLog(@"it entered active push");

        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.userInfo = userInfo;
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.alertBody = userInfo[@"aps"][@"alert"][@"body"];
        localNotification.alertLaunchImage= userInfo[@"acme1"];
        localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
    }
}


- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Remove the badge number
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:notification.alertBody
                                                       delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }

    // Set icon badge number to zero
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the app is active you will be notified by application:didReceiveLocalNotification: in app delegate only. There you can display custom banner like view on the top viewcontroller presented on the view hierarchy . Just look at the whatsapp notification when the app is open

Answer (score 2):

If the application is active then you will not recieve any sound, badge or alert, however the application delegate application:didReceiveLocalNotification: will be called

From apple docs

> If the application is foremost and visible when the system delivers the notification, no alert is shown, no icon is badged, and no sound is played. However, the application:didReceiveLocalNotification: is called if the application delegate implements it. The UILocalNotification instance is passed into this method, and the delegate can check its properties or access any custom data from the userInfo dictionary.

If your app is currently running and active (i.e. visible), you will not see the alert message. Instead iOS will deliver the notification to your app directly through the following method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
```

Answer (score 1):

No it will not play a sound or show a banner. However in your apps delegate , did receive notification will still be called where you can then show an alert view if you wish to notify a user.

You can however add audio manually.

```
 - (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:    (UILocalNotification *)notification
{

SystemSoundID systemSoundID;
NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"blip"
                                          withExtension:@"mp3"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &systemSoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(systemSoundID);
}
```

[Local notification in Foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044373/local-notification-in-foreground)